# How to programmatically check checkbox with dynamic model name?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a some checkboxes with dynamic model name like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in main.itemDetails">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="item.price"
  ng-click="itemChanged(item)" ng-model="checkboxes[item.name]">
   {{item.name}} - <b>{{item.price}} €</b>
   <br>
</label>
```

In my controller, I want to check some checkboxes if their model's name exists in array $scope.selectedItems.

I'm trying to do something like this but it isn't working:

```
for (var i = 0, j = $scope.selectedItems.length; i<j; i++) {
            $scope['selectedItems[i].name'].isChecked = true;
        }
```

for example if item.name = 'Item1' I want the model to be named $scope.Item1 and later I want to call `$scope.Item1.isChecked = true;`

What Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try $scope[$scope.selectedItems[i]['name']]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are storing the model in the `$scope.checkboxes`, so you can set its value to `true` like the code below.

```
for (var i = 0, j = $scope.selectedItems.length; i<j; i++) {
    $scope.checkboxes[$scope.selectedItems[i].name] = true;
}
```

Comment: it needs the "isChecked", like @Jackthomson answer

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I know, but the real model is `ng-model="checkboxes[item.name]"`, one of them has to be changed.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro what do I have to change? Something in my html?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro it works without changes in my html. But to be honest I don't quite get how it works... Can you explain it a little bit? What confuses me is that if I console.log $scope.checkboxes, i always get an empty array

Comment: @papakias Well the checkboxes 'array' is being binded from your ngModel directive, once you declared it from the view it will reflect on your `$scope`. Also, you have to watch the `$scope.checkboxes` because it doesn't hapen with the controller initialization you can try writin your checkbox on the html for example `<p>{{ checkboxes }}</p>` and you can see what is in there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your using a string literal here:

`for (var i = 0, j = $scope.selectedItems.length; i<j; i++) {
    $scope['selectedItems[i].name'].isChecked = true;`
}

Just change this to read:

`for (var i = 0, j = $scope.selectedItems.length; i<j; i++) {
    $scope[selectedItems[i].name].isChecked = true;
}`

Answer (score 2):

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.main = [{
    'name':'test1',
    'price':'23',
    'isChecked':false
    },
    {
    'name':'test2',
    'price': '25',
    'isChecked':false
    },
    {
    'name':'test3',
    'price': '21',
    'isChecked':false
    }];
    
    $scope.selectedItems = [{
    'name':'test1'
    },
    {
    'name':'test2'
    }];
    angular.forEach($scope.main, function(valueMain){
     angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems,function(valueSelected){
       if(valueMain.name=== valueSelected.name){
          valueMain.isChecked = true;
       }
      })
    
    });

    $scope.toggleCheck = function(item){
       if(item.isChecked === true){
         item.isChecked === false;
       }else{
         item.isChecked === true;
       }; 
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="item in main">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-checked="item.isChecked" ng-change="toggleCheck(item)">
   {{item.name}} - <b>{{item.price}} €</b>
   <br>
</label>
</div>
  </div>
```

Angular Foreach is the easiest way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Wow...this seems really good, I'll try it out and give you feedback!

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this code if I select test1 and test3 but not test2

Comment: Yes, You are right. I have corrected this issue. ng-model should be value of checked or not and for checking change, ng-change is required.